# Android WebView with embedded Flash not able to make external interface calls

Tags: javascript, android, flash, webview

I'm trying to display a full screen swf using the WebView. My goal is to have the swf call back into the javascript->java to call a function.  I've tried embedding my swf using swfobject and doing allowScriptAccess.  This method looks terrible for sizing, but alas, unable to call the external javascript.  The flash looks best when I do a loadUrl(file:///android_asset/file.swf?width=200&height=343) but this method also doesn't allow for external calls to be performed by flash.

Anyone have this issue?  I can call them fine from my javascript client code. Have the alert working and a couple other links.  Just missing some small piece in flash calls or permissioning i think.

We've tried in our flash.

```
ExternalInterface.call("window.alert", "test");
ExternalInterface.call("alert", "test");
ExternalInterface.call("window.histree.alert", "test");
```

This is my webview setup

```
   /* Get the WebView */
   wv1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv1);
   wv1.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

    /* Activate JavaScript */
    wv1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv1.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    wv1.setBackgroundColor(R.color.black);
    wv1.setWebViewClient(new InsideWebViewClient());
    wv1.addJavascriptInterface(new HistreeJavaScriptInterface(), "histree");

    wv1.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {          
        @Override
        public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
            AlertDialog.Builder adb=new AlertDialog.Builder(HistreeView.this);
            adb.setMessage(message);
            adb.setPositiveButton(R.string.OK, null);
            adb.show();         

            result.confirm();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: hi, I met the same issue. Have you got any progress on that? thanks

Comment: I have this up a while ago in favor of doing what I wanted to do in Flash as native Java